# CVXPY crashes on kernelized lasso

Tags: cvxpy

I'm attempting to run CVXPY to solve a kernelized lasso regression.

When the number of predictors goes up (my goal is to have 3000 of them), it crashes with either a "Killed" error or a "bad alloc" error.

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np
import scipy

np.random.seed(0)
NUM_PREDICTORS = 500
NUM_SAMPLES = 1
l1 = 10
x = np.random.randn(NUM_SAMPLES, NUM_PREDICTORS)
y = np.random.randn(NUM_SAMPLES, 1)
xx = x.T @ x
yx = y.T @ x
xx_sqrt = scipy.linalg.sqrtm(xx)
b = cp.Variable(yx.T.shape)
u = cp.sum_squares(xx_sqrt @ b) - cp.sum(2 * yx @ b) + l1 * cp.norm(b, 1)
obj = cp.Minimize(u)
prob = cp.Problem(obj)
prob.solve()
print('done')
```

Comment: You run out of memory (not uncommon when approach ML-sized tasks with general-purpose convex-opt solvers; although i don't know if the memory-error comes from the solver or even earlier when building the *convex model*).

Comment: I know I'm running out of memory. It's absolutely the solver. I want to know why it's running out of memory and if there's a way to do lasso on a large number of variables with a sane amount of memory.

Comment: Have you tried the solver Mosek?

Comment: Yes and it didn't help at all.